# Having issues with .size() method (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an assignment for college and there was two tester classes given one called GetMarks and another called Tester, but there seems to be something wrong with the tester. When trying to compile it after making no changes to the source code it fails to compile giving the error message stating; cannot find symbol - method size()

The code that is highlighted is:

> if (vw.getCars().size() == 3)

I have no idea how to amend this and no idea what the issue is. 
If anyone knows what i need to do I would be grateful. 
If you would like to see the entire source code of the whole project it's here. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yi7talq5yisvqqm/Assignment3.zip

Comment: Please post all the relevant code here; I'm not going to click on a link just to look at your source code.

Comment: Please provide more info: 'vw' is an object of what class?

Comment: there are four classes if i post all the code here it will surely be messy? I've never used this site before.

Comment: vw is an object of the CarManufacturer class

Comment: What type does `getCars` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getCars() method returns a String. You can't do a .size() on a String. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in the code. So you can start off by investigating what that line in **Tester.java** does and proceed from there.

**EDIT**

You have an attribute cars in **CarManufacturer.java**, which is an ArrayList. The getter for cars is modified to return String. Check that for starters.

Comment: What the tester is trying to do I think is get the size of the ArrayList<Car> cars for the manufacturer 'vw' Thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: You cant do that using getCars() because getCars() returns a String not an ArrayList.

Comment: I didn't write the tester and my code needs to work with the tester. So what i need to do is change the getCars() to return an ArrayList not a String for it to work?

Comment: Yes that would work, assuming it doesnt mess up some other part of the code which expects a String and not an ArrayList.

Comment: It's my mistake I figured it out I think. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the spec tells me nothing about a getCars method maybe that was my confusion I'll need to write one. Sorry

Comment: @user3081069 Its ok. Good that you figured it out. Next time post the relevant code along with your question.

Comment: I have fixed it's working now thanks for all the help it made me realise i needed a whole new method for it.

Answer (score 0):

what you can try doing is this. You can make a method that will return the ArrayList that is in the **CarManufacturer.java**, Something called getList() would work.

```
public int getList(){
 return this.cars;
}
```

Then when you do the statement vw.getList().size() it will return an integer value. Best of luck!